# How do I detect if a user is using the Lotus Notes browser?

Tags: browser, lotus-notes

We provide a web based platform to our clients and some content doesn't work properly when viewed through the Lotus Notes internal browser. Despite various warnings about not opening in Lotus, users are still doing it.

Therefore I need a reliable way to detect the Lotus browser and therefore block and display an appropriate message.

I can't see from the user agents in use any particular evidence of the agent specified and I have been advised Lotus may even spoof this.

Does anyone know how I can detect the Lotus Notes browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the Notes browser and got this User Agent:  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Lotus-Notes/6.0; Windows-NT)

Granted this is on Notes 6.0.4, but I imagine the internal Notes browser would still provide an accurate user-agent.

The problem might be, though, that people are using the integrated Internet Explorer browser, which would show up as some version of IE.

Comment: The actual issue we were having is the internal IE doesn't fire all JavaScript events hence why it appeared as IE but our site didn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible to detect this from the user-agent string then there are two other options.

1. Are any other identifying headers being sent specifically from the browser? (Probably not if you've got issues with user-agent rewriting or, presumably, proxies.)
2. Look at a way of detecting this in the browser with javascript.

For javascrpt based detection, try using one or more of:

```
navigator.appName; 
navigator.appVersion; 
navigator.appCodeName; 
navigator.platform;
```